Global exception handle in c++ to prevent crash
I am working migrating an old c++ application from OpenVMS to linux. The application heavily uses the os functionalities and we are struggling to find similar ones in linux. One is global exception handle by the os system library function that is callable from c++ code. This function catches the exception and uses sys$unwind function (another OpenVMS system function) to unwind the stack and jumps back to previous point/ function before exception. One of the reasons it is done to prevent system to crash when it tries to access another application or resources that might be unavailable. So rather than failing or crashing the application it goes back to the previous point and tries again.
I know its very risky and not ideal but I am looking for a similar library or function in c++/ linux.
I came across libunwind lib for linux but couldn't figure out how to use it to handle global exception and jump to a previous function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I think time would be better spent by debugging the program. If you need a safety net, add a monitoring process that restarts the program if it crashes.

linux doesn't really support an equivalent of OpenVMS's sys$unwind  (in fact, such a capability is almost entirely unique to VMS, AFAIK).   Rather than try to emulate such a thing, look to changing your code so it can detect if other resources it needs are available, rather than simply accessing them and dealing with the error.

You really do not want to do this. See my answer: C handle signal SIGFPE and continue execution Do what Ted suggested. fork a child and have the parent monitor the child for a crash. Restart the child if it ran for a few seconds (i.e. no immediate crash). (e.g.) int main(void) { while (1) { pid_t pid1 = fork(); if (pid1 == 0) { my_real_code(); exit(0); } pid_t pid2 = waitpid(pid1,&status,0); if (exited_normally or SIGTERM or SIGHUP) break; } return 0; }

@TedLyngmo Thanks unfortunatley the code base is huge and with limited capability to do debug.

@Peter Indeed that is the last option. However if I look at the size of the code that would be very difficult if not impossible

@CraigEstey Thanks. I considered that option. However one of the reason is this eixiting error handling is to retain the state. Restarting the process means loosing the state of the process which is not acceptable due to the nature of the application

@Ashiful Since you are porting it to Linux, you should have very good tools available. Asan, UBsan, Tsan and gdb to analyze core dumps etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Too long for a comment, so ...
C++ has try-throw-catch. You need to understand for what and why the VMS exception handling was used. There is/was a reason. VMS applications usually do not use exception handling to fix a divide by zero exception or segmentation fault (aka ACCESS violation) and to continue from the exception. They usually return an error status to an parent function/routine. That means that checking and returning a status does not have to be coded in each intermediate function.
That is, one or more functions enable a (their own) handler. The application (or the OS) signals an (OS or application defined) error code. All of the handlers in the call chain are called and decide if they can/want to handle the error condition. One of the handlers decides to unwind the stack, usually to return an error code from the function in which it (the handler) was enabled. There is always a handler. There is at least one handler in the RTL or in the OS - the last chance handler that usually prints traceback information. While unwinding, all the handlers are called again so that they can do any necessary cleanup.
With the libunwind library you should be able to implement VMS's exception handling. I would not even think of trying to do this. I would rather use the C++ language constructs and adjust or rewrite the code with this. But again, you need to understand for what and why the VMS exception handling was used.
I don't want to start a another answer, so I add something here. A quick and dirty example:
/*
 * cc -m64 -o ./unwind -L libunwind/src/.libs -lunwind -I libunwind/include/ unwind.c
 */
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UNW_LOCAL_ONLY
#include <libunwind.h>

static void unwind (void) {
        unw_cursor_t cursor; unw_context_t uc;
        unw_word_t ip;
        char proc_name[128];
        unw_word_t off;
        unw_getcontext(&uc);
        unw_init_local(&cursor, &uc);
        do {
                unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &ip);
                unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, proc_name, sizeof proc_name, &off);
                printf ("%s, %s, %lx\n", __func__, proc_name, (long) ip);
                if (0==strcmp("foo",proc_name))
                        break;
        }  while (unw_step(&cursor) > 0);
        unw_resume(&cursor);
        printf ("%s, oh no, it didn't work\n", __func__);
}

static void foobarhandler (int sig) {
        printf ("%s, sig %08x\n", __func__,sig);
        unwind();
        return;
}
static int foobar (void) {
        signal(SIGTERM,foobarhandler);
        printf ("%s\n", __func__);
        printf ("%s, raise SIGTERM\n", __func__);
        int s = raise(SIGTERM);
        printf ("back in %s, s: %08x\n", __func__, s);
        return 1;
}

static void bar (void) {
        printf ("%s\n", __func__);
        int s = foobar();
        printf ("back in %s, s: %08x\n", __func__, s);
}

static int foo () {
        printf ("%s\n", __func__);
        bar();
        printf ("back in %s\n", __func__);
        return 4711;
}

int main (void) {
        printf ("%s\n", __func__);
        int status = foo();;
        printf ("back in %s\n", __func__);
        printf ("%s, foo: %08x\n", __func__, status);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Expected output is:
main
foo
bar
foobar
foobar, raise SIGTERM
foobarhandler, sig 0000000f
unwind, unwind, 4008dc
unwind, foobarhandler, 4009e1
unwind, killpg, 7f01e062b400
unwind, gsignal, 7f01e062b387
unwind, foobar, 400a23
unwind, bar, 400a5d
unwind, foo, 400a8f
back in foo
back in main
main, foo: 00001267

The printed IPs should match the code addresses in the function, but I didn't double check.
I didn't try C++, which will have mangled names and finding the target call frame is not as easy as in plain C.
To find and call handlers in the call chain you need personality routines (.cfi_personality), which you do not get in C and what C++ adds is probably a common handler in the RTL and not a user defined one as on VMS.

Many thanks for the clarification. To be honest I also do not even dare to do such exception handling. Unfortunately I am given no chance to modify existing code at not not in the first pahse. After reading about libunwind I also thought this could be a similar solution. However I couldn't figure it out how to do that. I would appreciate if you could share a reference or give an example code showing how to do that. Thanks in advance

Thanks once again  much appreciated your kind effort with the example code
